# Coding three conditions in scatter plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make a `ggplot2` scatter plot (`geom_point`) where the points code for three different characteristics. So I thought of using `shape`, `colour` and `fill` (by using shapes 21 to 25 that can be filled). Although the plot itself looks fine, the legend doesn't show the fill colours (all the points appear black). Here is an MWE, note the black symbols for `carb`:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, shape = factor(gear),
                    fill = factor(carb), colour = factor(cyl)))
p + geom_point(size = 3) + scale_shape_manual(values = 21:25)
```

Is there a way to change the `fill`-legend so that it shows the real colours?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can map `color` and `fill` to different variables in `geom_point`. You shouldn't anyway.

Comment: @Roland The mapping itself does work (as in the MWE), it's just the legend that doesn't. And yes, I do need to code (at least) three features in one plot, it's not going to be a diagram with meaningful numbers but just an image showing the design of an experiment, similar to this one: http://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-microtiter-plate-maps/. However, if you have any suggestions for how else to code the third feature, I would be happy to know.

Comment: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, shape = factor(gear), colour = factor(carb))) + geom_point(size = 3) + facet_grid(.~cyl)` would be a better plot.

Comment: @Roland Please have a look at the weblink provided. Once again: I'm not going to plot meaningful numbers but a plate design. A microtiter plate cannot be faceted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works, changing the shape in the fill legend to 21:

```
p + geom_point(size = 3) + 
    scale_shape_manual(values = 21:25)+
      scale_fill_discrete(guide=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=21)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks perfect! Do you know if it's possible to make the coloured lines around the points thicker so that they become more visible on the plot?

Comment: I was just going to suggest that.  I think adjusting the linewidth (`lwd`) will help.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting `lwd` in `geom_point` does not do anything.

Comment: This seems to be the answer to the `lwd` story: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677687/change-thickness-of-a-marker-in-ggplot2
Thanks for your help!